# Can new line be added to http header in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

can I add "\n" as in this example in line 5?
In case I can, will hahaha appear in http response body?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': body.length,
  'Location' : 'http://www.aaa.com\nhahaha',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you trying to inject the body using a Location header in the first place?

Comment: it's not about location header, I just want to know if it's possible, it could be any other header, including non standard headers

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Lets say I am writing a header and as value of header I will write some value form some file and I am not sure of it's content, should I check for \n or node will take care of this for me by not allowing "\n" or "\r\n" inside headers value.

Comment: Was it actually quicker to ask this question on stackoverflow than to just run the code you wrote and use `curl` or even your browser developer tools to check?

Comment: Since it was almost quicker to run your code (but I had to edit it for errors) I did - the answer appears to be the newline is stripped in the header. so you get `Location: http://www.aaa.comhahaha` as the header entry.

Comment: don't form blind headers. "as value of header I will write some value form some file and I am not sure of it's content" should never be the case. If it is, you're being a bad programmer and need to first learn what the value is, and make it HTTP spec compliant for header content.

Answer (score -1):

Node will filter the \n

So, as a result there will be no injection using this code ..